# appending into middle of a string using sed

Tags: sed

I am completely new to sed script. I want to make a script so that it asks user to enter value to be inserted in file. I am not able to find the correct code

so the line I have in the text file looks like this

```
path =
```

I want to input path from user so the line looks like:

```
path = /dev
```

Through trial and error I only have:

```
read -p "Enter path name: " PT
echo "$( sed -i '/path/ s/.*/& $PT/' textfile )"
```

which gives

```
path = $PT
```

can you help me with correct code

Comment: What is "sed script"? Are you new to the command `sed` or are you new to scripting? If the latter please indicate what shell you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
read -p "Enter path name: " PT
sed -i "/path/ s#.*#& $PT#" textfile
```

You need to use double quotes, not single quotes.  Single quotes protects a string from the shell, but in this case you want the shell to expand the value of `$PT`.

Also,

```
echo "$( ... )"
```

is the same as just `...` (the stuff in the `$( ... )`).

Answer (score 0):

Variable expansion doesn't happen within single quote, use double quote instead.

+ since your variable will contains `/` as part of path. with GNU `sed` you should use different substitution delimiter.

```
read -p "Enter path name: " PT
sed -i "\#path# s#.*#& $PT#" infile
```