# insert to the middle of a line in a textfile using sed

Tags: linux, sed

I have been researching how to add text to a line in file.

so the line I have in the text file looks like this

```
hosts allow = 192.168.122. 172.24.0
```

i want to add IP so line looks like

```
hosts allow = 192.168.122.  192.12.0.  172.24.0
```

Through trial and error I only have:

```
sed -i '/allow/ s/.*/&,192.12.0./' testfile
```

which gives:

```
hosts allow = 192.168.122. 172.24.0. 192.12.0.
```

Comment: seems your have two accounts, and your question is duplicated of previous one here https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/392985/72456

Comment: no, its different question

Comment: That `sed` command would not produce the line that you mention. Where did the comma go?

Comment: cross posting :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46282502/insert-to-the-middle-of-a-line-in-a-textfile-sed/46284679#46284679

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` to insert the string as the second to last field on the line:

```
$ awk '/allow/ { $(NF+1) = $NF; $(NF-1) = "192.12.0." } { print }' file
hosts allow = 192.168.122. 192.12.0. 172.24.0
```

The first block will be executed for any line in `file` containing the string `allow`.  It will first move the last field, `$NF`, one step further along, to `$(NF+1)`.  This increases `NF` by one. It then assigns the string to the second to last field, `$(NF-1)`.

All lines are then printed.

Redirect the output from this to a new file and move that file into place:

```
awk ...as above... file >file.new && mv file.new file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/= [^ ]*/& 192.12.0/'
```

Captures the `=` sign, the space and all characters before the next space. That is, this part `= 192.168.122.`. Then, replaces all matching characters to themselves - `&` (in other words, doesn't change this part, just returns it back), plus adds the needed ip `192.12.0`.

**Input**

```
hosts allow = 192.168.122. 172.24.0
```

**Output**

```
hosts allow = 192.168.122. 192.12.0 172.24.0
```