# inserting in the line using sed

Tags: linux, sed

the text in file looks like this:

```
[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        path = 
        browseable = 
        writable = yes
        valid users = %S
        valid users = MYDOMAIN\%S

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        browseable = no
        guest ok = no
        writable = no
        printable = yes
```

i want output as:

```
[homes]
        comment = Home Directories
        path = /data
        browseable = yes
        writable = yes
        valid users = %S
        valid users = MYDOMAIN\%S

[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        browseable = no
        guest ok = no
        writable = no
        printable = yes
```

i am using this command:

```
sed -i "\#path# s#.*#& /data#" file
```

but it makes changes to everywhere in file where path is located

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: you could always comment under your posts instead of opening new questions for each [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/392996/72456) then [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/392985/72456) and now this with same requirement but different issues!

Answer (score 3):

Be more specific in your regular expression:

```
sed '/path *= *$/ s#$#/data#' file.ini
```

The expression `/path *= *$/` will match any line with `path` followed by `=` (possibly surrounded by spaces), but with nothing other than spaces after that and the end of line.  The actual substitution will place `/data` at the end of the line.

This would work too:

```
sed "s#path *= *$#& /data#" file.ini
```

If you need to be more specific with what section of the INI-file you want to modify, then expand the range of the `s` command:

```
sed '/\[homes\]/,/\[printers\]/ s#path *= *$#& /dev#' file.ini
```

This will only apply the substitution to the `[homes]` section.

Redirect to a new file or use `-i` in the appropriate way with any of the above solutions.